# CSV file imported to SQLite trims rows

Tags: sqlite, csv

I have a CSV file that has 2999 rows but on importing it to a table in sqlite3, I get only 1363 rows. The following are the set of commands/queries I'm using. Unfortunately I cannot link to the raw data here for confidentiality reasons. Given that, can anybody point out what I may be missing or if there is any limit to import sizes (sorry, Google didn't help me)? Thanks in advance.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (var1 integer, var2 integer, var3 varchar(50));
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import data-v1.csv test                                                           
sqlite> select count(*) from test;
```

The output is 1363 when it should have been 2999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb ... there was a ^M instead of a newline character at a bunch of rows (not everywhere).